# Python str.split() and list creation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently learning python through "Python Programming: An Intro to CS" and everything has been crystal clear up until splitting a string into a list. Overall I get the gist of `str.split()` but just found something a bit quirky.

The book has the following example:

```
>>> myString = "Hello, string methods!"
>>> myString.split()
['Hello,' , 'string' , 'methods!']
```

Author states that `myString` has now been split into a *list of three substrings*.

Continuing on, doing this turns `myString` into a list:

```
>>> myString = "Hello, string methods!"
>>> myString2 = myString.split()
>>> myString2
['Hello,' , 'string' , 'methods!']
```

So far so good.

After experimenting on my own with the shell, I found the following:

```
# Testing splitting of variable x
>>> x = "Pleased to meet you"
>>> x
'Pleased to meet you'
>>> x.split()
['Pleased', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
>>> type(x)
**<class 'str'>**

# Testing behavior of splitting 'x' by assigning it to 'y'
>>> y = x.split()
>>> y
['Pleased', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
>>> type(y)
**<class 'list'>**
```

Why does `x.split()` still make `x` a `str`, while `y = x.split()` turns it into a list?

Why does python behave this way and what's really going on? Is there anyway to apply .split on a variable and get a list, or am I always going to get a str type?

Comment: x.split() _returns_ a list - you do not assign it back to x. so x is still a string. assign the return of `x.split()` to a variable - and check that ones type.

Comment: Uh, `str.split` doesn't modify the original string object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable, the `str.split()` method doesn't change the string you split. Instead, a *new list* is returned. You got confused by what happens in the shell when you don't assign the result of an expression and just echo that result instead.

When you executed `x.split()`, the new list was returned and echoed in the shell. That list was not referenced by anything else, and `x` still points to the original string, which didn't change. `type(x)` shows that `x` still points to the original string.

Next, you actually assigned the list that `str.split()` produced, to a new name `y`. You then echoed `y` and tested the type of `y`, which is the list object produced by `str.split()`. That's logical, because you told Python to make `y` a reference to the result of `x.split()`. `type(y)` tells you that `y` references a list object.

I strongly recommend you read the excellent [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by Ned Batchelder, it explains, in very clear terms, how names (like `x` and `y`) are different from the Python objects like the string `"Hello, string methods!"` or the list `['Pleased', 'to', 'meet', 'you']`.

Comment: Love the explanation Martjin! Gosh I feel so dumb. It’s something so simple but doing the testing through the shell made it a little more complicated than it was. It really was quite petty. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

The key point here is that `str.split()` **returns** a list, it doesn't affect the string itself. So `y = x.split()` is setting `y` to the list returned by the function, but `x` itself is unaffected.

Comment: Thank you. Clearly a brain fart! Maybe I need a break?

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns the result of splitting the string as a list but does not modify the string itself.  You can capture that list via the assignment `y = x.split()` to capture its output, but `x` itself is unmodified.